# Plugin development - loading Javascript and Flash

Tags: plugin-development

I've been using Wordpress for a while, and I really like it \o/...  I've written plugins for the Joomla platform but I'm sort of struggling getting going on the wordpress platform :

Here's my plan.  I'm in the process of writing a plugin that uses Flash to allow the user to record audio from the soundcard (my idea is to allow the user to record a podcast through the web site).

I have a questions (so many questions...) but I'll go with these few :

I am using wp-enqueue to load the Javascript libraries into the page or post as it is loaded.  Currently I'm using add_action('init', 'register_libraries'); to register the javascript libraries - and I think that works - but it also shows in the administration page (where this plugin won't be used).

So I had a look a the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) page and it suggests that I should be using init - it says that init is "Typically used by plugins to initialize".  But that also includes the administration side, which I don't want for this plugin.  Any suggestions what I should do instead?

In addition, and perhaps this should be a separate question - I wanted to load flash during the loading of the plugin - how should I do that - any ideas?...

I know... It's a bit noobish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `wp_print_scripts` hook for your scripts instead of `init` and in your callback make sure that you are not in the administration pages something like this:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','register_libraries');
function register_libraries(){
    if (!is_admin()){
     //enqueue your scripts here
    }
}
```

as for adding flash, that should be a separate question just make sure to add more details about it.

Comment: Any reason you're recommending using `wp_print_scripts`, rather than `wp_enqueue_scripts`? +1 for the `if ( ! is_admin() )` suggestion, regardless.

Comment: @ChipBennett good question, it would work either way but its not my favorite workflow, `wp_print_scripts` is the action that runs when scripts are output to the template. `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` are functions for registering/enqueueing scripts to be output when `wp_print_scripts` runs. so in this point it makes no difference

Comment: Thanks... i'll add the admin check into my code, and try the wo_print_scripts.  I think there's a bit of reading for me to do through the codex...

Comment: @Bainternet but you're *enqueueing* scripts; semantically that should be done at the hook for *enqueueing* scripts. Practically, it should be done there, just as a matter of considerate practice, so that there are still later hooks available to override the action. I treat `wp_print_scripts` as a last resort only.

Comment: @ChipBennett that approach is correct in my book too but you still have a filter to remove scripts even at that point.